# Can set builder notation be used to refine function types?

Tags: functions

From my understanding, when defining a function you provide a function signature which provides some restriction for how the function behaves. I guess we can use set builder notation here to make this more expressive, before providing the implementation? e.g.

$e: U \xrightarrow{} U \\
e \subseteq\ \{(u_1, u_2) \in U \times U \mid u_2 \subseteq\ u_1\} \\
e = \{ X \mapsto Y\}, \ Y \subseteq\ X, \ X \in\ U$

Comment: What does $X \mapsto Y$ mean?

Comment: the element X maps to the element Y

Comment: Your "implementations" are loose specifications. They rely on the signature to ensure that $e$ actually is a function rather than a more general relation. Note that there are also some differences between the use of $\mapsto$ by mathematicians (typically topologists or category theorists, who use it as a syntax for $\lambda$-abstraction: $x \mapsto f(x)$ means $\lambda x.f(x)$ for them) and some computer scientists (specifically those used to the Z notation, who use $x \mapsto y$ as a synonym for the ordered pair $(x, y)$).

Comment: Hi @RobArthan , I was using $X \mapsto Y$ as an ordered pair. In this example there is just one mapping and so it is a total function, and therefore doesn't rely on the specification for this information?

Comment: Look at your second formula: $e \subseteq\ \{(u_1, u_2) \in U \times U \mid u_2 \subseteq\ u_1\}$: in general, this does not imply that $e$ is a function: e.g., you could include any pair $(u_1, u_2) \in U \times U$ with $u_2 \subseteq u_1$ and then without any further assumptions on $U$ you will get lots of $u_2$s for any given $u_1$.

Comment: Sure, when mentioned implementation I was referring to the last line, and the line you mention is part of the specification, I agree. Both the first two lines are conjuncts of the spec and together they constrain the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat vague, but yes, you can do this.

Set theory comes with something known as the "axiom of separation". It states that whenever $P(x)$ is any statement not containing the variable $Q$, and whenever $S$ is a set, there is some set $Q$ such that for all $x$, $x \in q$ if and only if $x \in S$ and $P(x)$.

This set $Q$ is denoted $\{x \in S \mid P(x)\}$.

Note that given sets $A, B$, there is a set $B^A$ of all functions from $A$ to $B$. We often write $x : A \to B$ as shorthand for $x \in B^A$.

So we can construct sets such as $\{f : U \to U \mid \forall u \in U (u \subseteq f(u))\}$ (which is just translating your requirement of $\forall (u_1, u_2) \in e$, $u_1 \subseteq u_2$ into more standard terminology).

Typically, mathematicians will give the function a domain and a codomain, define the function, state properties of the function, and prove these properties (in that order). So it would be rare to say "We define $f \in \{f : U \to U \mid P(f)\}$ by ..."

Instead, a mathematician would define $f : U \to U$ and then prove $P(f)$.

Comment: Hi i'm coming from computer science, the idea is to define expressive types which restricts the possible definitions so when a definition is provided it conforms.

Comment: @newlogic You should look into type theory and proof assistants such as Coq.

Comment: guess you can also do it as $f: U \to U , \ \forall u \in U (u \subseteq f(u))$ ? i.e without the set to reduce syntax

Comment: @newlogic Yes. This is another way to state the condition.